# htaccess redirecting index, no file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I just ran into this. I'm running a wordpress website, and I'll like to redirect this www.dentistcostamesadds.com/index to www.dentistcostamesadds.com. My code below doesn't work.

```
# Permanent URL redirects
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /index http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com
```

As you can see below, only the **/index** without the **extension** doesn't work. Why?

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com WORKS
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com WORKS
Redirect 301 /index.aspx http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com WORKS
Redirect 301 /home http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com WORKS
Redirect 301 /home.html http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com WORKS
Redirect 301 /index http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com DOESN'T WORK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `Redirect` directive automatically appends the rest of the URI to the target. So if you have only:

```
Redirect 301 /abc http://domain.com/xyz
```

This means a request for `/abc1234` will get redirected to `http://domain.com/xyz1234`, and `/abc/foo/bar` gets redirected to `http://domain.com/xyz/foo/bar`. So if you want to redirect all those things, you can try a regex instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(index|home)(\.php|\.html|\.aspx)?$ http://www.dentistcostamesadds.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index?$                               /
```

This says redirect requests to www.(...)/index to www.(...)

Where www.(...) is the domain.